# Passing environment variables to myrepos (mr)

Tags: git, perl, haskell, configuration, mercurial

I'm using joey hess' myrepos tool to manage multiple repos.

At some point, I'd like to pass environment variables to actions and sections so that they get expanded. In particular, I'm passing things like `$SYNCTL`, which should point to the top level directory where repositores are mounted.

(Note that this has nothing to do with the top-level dir as refered to by myrepos: that's the top level dir above which everything should be ignored, which is different.)

Unfortunately, those variables are not being expanded.

For instance, if I export `SYNCTL=/home/myuser` and then define the repo:

```
[$SYNCTL/myrepo]
```

in `.mrconfig`

that is never actually found. `$SYNCTL` is expanded to nothing, which results in myrepos looking for `/myrepo`, which obviously does not exist, so myrepos just ignores that section.

I also tried to expand the variable inside the repo section, like so:

```
[myrepo]
status = echo $SYNCTL
```

but that does not print anything either. In this case, the repo is found, but a blank line is printed.

There are some variables that can be expanded (like `HOME`), but not all seem to work. I thought it had something to do with `--force-env`, but running `mr --force-env status` does not print anything either.

Is there any way to work around this problem? Should there be?

Comment: I don't really know anything about myrepos, but "the repo is found, but a blank line is printed" sounds to me like `SYNCTL` isn't being exported properly. Can you double-check (e.g. with `env | grep SYNCTL`, assuming that's actually the `env` program and not a shell built-in for your shell) that it is being exported and not just defined local to your shell?

Comment: It was as simple as that. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that you export the `SYNCTL` environment variable. For example, in `bash`-alikes, instead of

```
SYNCTL=$HOME/reponame
```

which only defines a shell-local variable, use

```
export SYNCTL=$HOME/reponame
```

to make an environment variable that will be inherited by spawned processes.